# Data exchange between records very slow

Tags: java, sockets, network-protocols

We have huge record set on AIX box that we send over network to Linux box and process it.
Each record is about 277 bytes in size.

complete flow is like:

i) Program A sends records to java process B (both on AIX box).

ii) Java process B on AIX sends the records to java Program C on linux. Both are communicating through java sockets where B is client and C is server.

iii) Program C processes each record and sends an ACK back to Program B.

iv) Program B sends ACK back to Program A, which then sends next record.

I tihnk all these ACKs eat up the network and overall process is becoming very slow. For eg. in latest run, it processed 330,000 records in 4 hours and then we got a socket reset and client failed.

I was trying to find out that what would be better protocol in this case to have less network traffic and finish up faster. 330,000 records in 4 hours is really slow as processing each record on Program C takes less than 5-10 seconds but over-all flow is such that we are facing this slowness issue.

Thanks in advance,

-JJ

Comment: why are you sending the records one by one?

Comment: @Mat - This is limitation of the client. The client will send records one by one only. I cannot control it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting for the ack to go all the way back to A before sending the next record will definitely slow you down because C is essentially idle while this is happening.  Why don't you move to a queuing architecture?  Why not create a persistent queue on C which can receive the records from A (via B) and then have one (or many) processors for this queue sitting on C.

This way you decouple how fast A can send from how fast C can process them.  A's ack becomes the fact that the message was delivered to the queue successfully.  I would use [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq/) for this purpose.

**EDIT**

The HornetQ getting-started guide is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.2.Final/quickstart-guide/en/html_single/index.html.).

If you can't use this, for the simplest non-persistent in-memory queue, simply use a ThreadPoolExecutor from Java's concurrency libraries.  You create a ThreadPoolExecutor like this:

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(
    threadPoolSize, threadPoolSize, KEEP_ALIVE, MILLISECONDS,
    new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(queueSize), ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy.discardOldest());
```

Where queueSize can be MAX_INT.  You call execute() with a Runnable on the ThreadPool to get tasks to be carried out.  So your receiving code in C can simply pop these Runnables created and parameterized with the Record on to the ThreadPool and then return the ack immediately to A (via B).

Comment: @alpian - good advice. If B sends ACK back to A and then sends all recors to B, would C be able to handle and process so many records that B is sending to it ? Could you point to some example of presistent queue at C to deal with this situation so that C is able to receive all messages from B and not drop anything. Just bit confused how C will handle a huge load of messages coming from B. Also I cannot use any open-saource or third party tools. So, I have to restrict myself to what java provides..

Comment: @user656189: C's persistent queue would be handled by a HornetQ server.  Basically, HornetQ would write them to disk (a journal) on C and the processor on C would pick them up and process them.  All this is handled by the API - you just need to write a MessageConsumer.  Therefore as long as you have enough disk space on C there's no theoretical limit to the number of messages you can receive.  If the acks aren't critical and you want it to go faster, you could just have a non-persistent queue instead.

Comment: @alpian - appreciate your response ! I cannot go outside Java for any open source/thrid party tool. Could you point me to some non-persistent queue example.

Comment: HornetQ is an open-source Java tool/library.  I'm not sure if you can use it - it's open source.  If you can only use the JDK then you can easily implement a non-persistent queue by using Java concurrency.  I'll add the link and example to the answer.

Comment: @alpian - I got it working without any queue. But just sending one ack after few thousand records rather than 1 ack after every record.

Comment: user656189: Great!  At least this way you're avoiding the network delay.

Answer (score 1):

If each record takes 5 seconds, and there are 330,000 record, this should take 1,650,000 seconds which is 19 days.  If you are taking 4 hours to process 330,000 records, are they not taking 43 ms.

One reason they might take 43 ms per request is if you are creating a closing a connection for each request.  It could be sending most of its time creating/closing rather than doing. A simple way around this is to create a connection once, and only reconnect if there is an error.

If you use a persistent connection your overhead could drop below 100 micro-seconds per request.

Is there any reason you cannot send a batch of data of say 1000 records to process, which would return 1 ACK and cut the overhead by a factor of 1000?

Comment: We have one persistent connection for this transaction as you pointed out. Also your calculation for each record time is correct. It is not 5-10 sec but few micro seconds. I was also thinking of lines of 1 ACK for few thousand records, was just trying to verify it here. Thanks for the response !